# Getting environmental variable is undefined in React js

Tags: reactjs, webpack, environment-variables

I want to store variable in .env variable and use it like process.env

I added .env file in root directory

```
REACT_APP_FOO = abcc111
```

webpack.config.dev.js

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        React: 'react'
    }),
     new webpack.DefinePlugin({
       "process.env":{
       'REACT_APP_FOO': JSON.stringify(process.env.REACT_APP_FOO)
     }
   })
],
```

App.js

```
console.log(process.env);
```

Result is:

```
{REACT_APP_FOO: undefined}
```

Please let me know if i am missing anything here.

Comment: In .env try REACT_APP_FOO=abcc111 (remove whitespace before and after equal sign)

Comment: @henrik123 still getting same result  {REACT_APP_FOO: undefined}

Answer (score 1):

Steps to add `.env` contents

1) `npm install dotenv --save`

2) At top of webpack config file

`const dotenv = require('dotenv').config({path: __dirname + '/.env'});`

3) Then create a .env file at the root directory of your application and add the variables to it.

//contents of .env

`REACT_APP_FOO = abcc111`

4) webpack config file

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env": dotenv.parsed
        }),
```

4) Add `.env` to your `.gitignore` file so that Git ignores it and it never ends up on GitHub. Need to restart application after adding variable in .env file.

**If you are using create-react-app, it uses `react-scripts` which has dependency of `dotenv` so you don't have to install and configure, you could just create `.env` file and use in your application.**
**Convention being name should start with REACT_APP**

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using any external library? @tarzen

Comment: whenever i install this library . i get issues with other library

Comment: You need this library to get variables from .env file and add them to process.env. This library has zero dependency and is internally used by create-react-app also. It shouldn't be conflicting with other library. What is the error you are getting. If you can't install this library then just set environment variables in webpack cli like `webpack --env.REACT_APP_FOO= abcc111 --config webpack.config.js`